# java instance variable and method having same name

Tags: java

In java can an instance variable and a method have the same name without any instability or conflict?

I want to make sure if I can get away with compiling it, that it wont cause any error down the road.

Comment: Why didn't you just try it by yourself? :)

Comment: This is not allowed in c#.

Comment: Just because it's allowed doesn't mean it's a good idea. I just wasted hours chasing down a NPE all because the field was accidentally used instead of the method. If you want to avoid errors down the road avoid this anti-pattern. Good for C# for not allowing it.

Comment: @jibbs, Given that a NPE is runtime, how did you manage to reference a field (instead of the method) and get it by the compiler in the first place?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes it's fine, mainly because, syntactically ,  they're used differently.

Comment: Though you are correct - it is possible, I don't think the "syntaticall differently" reason is correct. My C++ is rusty, but I think in C++, they are also used differently but it will cause problems. for example: http://ideone.com/SQWav

Comment: @amit - Good point, let me study this issue and I'll then amend the answer. Thank You Very Much

Comment: @arshajii or did you mean: ! Java.equals(C++) ?

Comment: @arshajii For C++, it is perfectly valid to have defined a `!=` operator which does value inequality comparison instead of reference inequality comparison! I could agree with you if he had written `Java != C++` though. ;)

Comment: @arshajii yea, it is different. I did not say that this is not correct (and it does not work on java) I only said the supplied reason is not enough - unless backed by a citation from the specs that explains why it is enough - with a counter example of a different language - where it is also used syntatically different, but has different behavior. This means that a global answer like the one given is not enough, and a good answer should provide a citation from the specs explainig why it is the case.

Answer (score 8):

It's completely fine because methods and variables are called differently.

**Code:**

```
String name = "myVariable";

public String name() {
    return "myMethod";
}

System.out.println(name()); // Brackets for method call
System.out.println(name); // No brackets for variable call
```

**Output:**

> myMethod
>
> myVariable

Answer (score 4):

**The only conflict I could think of is**

```
int sameName = 5;

public int sameName() {
  //method body
  return 100;
}
```

If you write ***"this.sameName"*** when you are supposed to write ***"this.sameName()"*** and *vice-versa* at some place in the program then annihilation of the code has just begun.

Comment: But that would just be a bug. It's still legal. :D

Comment: Except if he encapsulated the field and made it private.

Comment: I faced SpEL execution regression for this case (after upgrade from Spring Boot 2.1 (ok) to 2.5.2 (error)).

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it is an anti pattern, should be avoided, and can be caught by analytics like so:

http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/naming.html

Comment: It should be caught by the compiler. I notice that the standard Java library does this. java.lang.String.hash32() and java.lang.String.hash32

Answer (score 3):

I actually have ran into an issue, which is very specific. It just manifests itself in Java 8 (using Nashorn), but not in Java 6 (using Rhino). If it try to access an instance variable of a Java object via Javascript, the `[]` operator returns the method instance instead.

Let's suppose I'm running the following Java declaration:

```
class MyClass {
    private boolean isSet=false;
    public boolean isSet() { return isSet; }
}
```

If I manipulate an object of such class in Javascript, and then try to access it with `[]` operator, I get the method reference.

```
var obj = new MyClass();
var myfields = (myclass.getClass()).getDeclaredFields();
var myfieldname = myfields[0].name;

// The following prints the method declaration, not the boolean value:
// [jdk.internal.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod boolean MyClass.isSet()]
println( obj[myfieldname] );
```

UPDATE: Apparently [Nashorn's method overloading resolution mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147370) ("implicitly" or non-intentionally) gives higher precedence to methods without arguments over instance fields with the same name.