# How many objects in this class?

Tags: java

```
public class A {
    private static int a=0;
    private static A a()
    {
        a++;
        return new A();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // main method will not be changed
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(a().a);
        System.out.println(a().a().a);
        System.out.println(a().a().a);
    }
}
/*
 * expected output
 * 0
 * 1
 * 3
 * 5
 * 7
```

Can you please tell me how many objects in this class? a() method or integer a object? I can't understand if there are static methods,variables we don't need object to call them,but how? a().a? what is this mean

Answer (score 0):

if you run your code you will get

```
0
1
3
5
```

Even though "`a`" is a static variable you can access it from an object. Regarding why it is accessible even though declared as `private`, well it is possible only because you are trying to access it from same class inside `main` method.

You are always allowed to declare same name for `method` and `variable` so it is [fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960560/java-instance-variable-and-method-having-same-name) to have "`a`" as both variable and method in your case. If you want your expected output just change your code as below

```
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(a().a);
System.out.println(a().a().a);
System.out.println(a().a().a);
System.out.println(a().a().a);
```

Answer (score 0):

one difference between static and non-static methods that you could create objects of it and every object contains unique data .static methods don't allow you to do  that but you can call methods on it directly (methods which it contains) 
this static method can't hold various data as non static methods'objects do but it seems  to be useful at some cases
 for example when you use a class to load data and filter it and sort it based on certain critera ,you want to use this data as it is in many places so you don't need make objects so you make this class static

Comment: first it takes 1 and then 3 and then 5?

Comment: yes,they do.. object can store their own data which can be different from other objects although they are instances of one class

Comment: you won't be able to acces your static and private variables and methods as you do now if you are working outside this class

Comment: but can't i call static method in test class?

Comment: ofcourse you can do that  .for example if i have static methods which i put all together in a class called database and i have created a new class named tester to do some tests and i want to call some of these methods ,i could do that through this line ....database.methodname(signature);